# How does one use the free Wolfram Engine for developers on Linux?

Tags: scripting, free-wolfram-engine

I just downloaded `wolframscript` on Linux. Downloading the ["free wolfram engine for developers"](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) gives me a `WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh`. I tried executing it but nothing happened.

How does one use this with `wolframscript`?

Comment: Here is the support document for Linux:  http://support.wolfram.com/kb/46072

Comment: True, but I was never able to register it myself using the "getting started" document instructions.  Additionally, it is quite annoying, to say the least, that there is no "uninstall" option to that script.  Also, why not allow local installation into users' home dirs?

Comment: @ILMostro_7 Exactly the same here! I have not managed to activate my installation. I have written to Wolfram Research twice, but to no avail. They have not responded to my messages. If you do figure out a solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 6):

It needs to be executed under root user, and it is a shell script, so run

```bash
sudo bash WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh
```

then wait for it to do its thing (the installation is interactive, it needs to be monitored).

This is what the http://support.wolfram.com/kb/46072 says, actually.

Comment: Related "getting started" question. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine The thing is, Wolfram Engine does not come with the Notebook interface, as that is a Mathematica thing.