# how can I auto complete the code in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I just noticed that we could use `Wolfram Language` from [How to add front-end to the free Wolfram Engine?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine).

After a while of playing with `Wolfram Language` in `Jupyter notebook`, I noticed I could not auto-complete the code with `Tab`.

I wonder how I can auto-complete the code.

Thanks.

Comment: The Jupyter integration is open source, and in this case, I think it is actually reasonable to say that you could implement this feature yourself (assuming you have 2 days to work on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS

and

https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram

have autocompletion. 
I think they are still better alternatives to the official WRI jupyter Kernel which is not mature yet. 
`IWolfram` must be tweaked a little to work with the new Wolfram Engine but
 `JWLS`  works out of the box  insofar it has been designed to run exclusively through wolframscript; as such, it works independently of what type of wolfram product you have installed.

**EDIT**: Linux users might prefer https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLX

Comment: I could not get iwolfram working on macOS. It just hangs when I try to set it up.

Comment: I think IWolfram set-up needs to be cleaned up by getting rid of its attempt to include Mathics and its checks on the initial response of the REPL. Then it might get installed. Did you try `JWLS` on Mac?

Comment: @Fortsaint: Is the JWLX version also compatible with macOS?

Comment: It is not insofar it relies on ramdisk /dev/shm. You would need to you replace that device with the corresponding one on macOS.

Answer (score 13):

Currently, this feature is not included.

If you are considering implementing it, you would need to start here:

https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html#handling-messages

You would need to implement handling the relevant messages. As far as I can tell, that would be [`complete_request`](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html#completion).  In Mathematica, you can use `Names["something*"]` to retrieve possible matches, which then can be returned to Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I am considering it. Maybe I can have a try after I graduate after next month. 囧rz.

Comment: @PureLine You do not need to accept the answer so soon. Maybe someone will actually implement it in an answer ... while _asking_ for that would be too much for StackExchange, I can imagine that someone would get sufficiently interested.