# TraditionalForm-like typesetting in Jupyter notebook

Tags: front-end, formatting, jupyter-notebook, free-wolfram-engine

One of the nice thing about running Mathematica codes in the front-end,
is that one can attach custom typesetting rules to the user-defined symbols.
Then, setting the format type of new output cells to `TraditionalForm`
provides you with a nice output similar to what one sees in papers and
textbooks.

Suppose that someone wants to use my package (that comes with extensive
typesetting rules) with the free Wolfram Engine, where the front-end
is a Jupyter notebook. As far as I can see, no typesetting is displayed
by default.

As a minimal working example, consider the following code.

```
cf /: MakeBoxes[cf[i_], TraditionalForm] := SubscriptBox["c", i];
SMP /: MakeBoxes[SMP["g_W"], TraditionalForm] := 
  SubscriptBox["g", "W"];
MakeBoxes[myvec[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
  TemplateBox[{OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"]}, "Abs"];
MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[
    TemplateBox[{OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"]}, "Abs"], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; OddQ[n];
MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; EvenQ[n];
```

In Mathematica, for

```
SMP["g_W"] (cf[1] myvec[v] + cf[2] myvec[v]^2 + cf[3] myvec[v]^3)
```

I get the expected typesetted output, but in Jupyter
this is not the case.

[image: Mathematica output]
[image: Jupyter output]

Is there something that can be tweaked in the notebook configuration or
in the package source code, to get the typesetting working?

Comment: Where is `TraditionalForm` set for `In[17]`?

Comment: I have _not_ tried this, but please try adding `//StandardForm` or `//TraditionalForm`

Comment: Actually, you are only defining it for TraditionalForm, so use `//TraditionalForm`

Comment: WOW, with TraditionalForm it just works! Sorry guys, I always have my format type of new output cells set to `TraditionalForm` in Mathematica, so I didn't think that it is `StandardForm` in Jupyter by default, although it is quite logical. BTW, is there a way to make Jupyter always output `TraditionalForm` by default?

Comment: `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> TraditionalForm]`? ( try it, I don't know, I have not used WE yet)

Comment: @Kuba Nope, that doesn't seem to work. I also tried setting `$Post` and `$PrePrint` to `TraditionalForm` but it looks like those do not really change anything in the Jupyter output. Since there is no `$FrontEndSession`, I also cannot assign a value to its `CommonDefaultFormatTypes`. Other suggestions?

Comment: @vsht I am not a Jupyter expert, but maybe a frontend-hook like [execute.CodeCell](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2321#issuecomment-288072177) could be written to behave like `$Post` ? [This](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development_guide/js_events.html) list of Javascript events might be useful, too.

Comment: How did you get Wolfram Kernel to work on Jupyter notebooks in the first place?

Comment: @QuantumDot https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198839/5478

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just use StandardForm because the loop WE-Jupyter is tricky to hook to.

I guess this solution won't work once WLforJupyter is out of beta stage but anyway:

```
toOut = toOutImage @* TraditionalForm;
toOut /: (toOut = _) := Null;
```

It is not a joke :)

[image]

#### Explanation

`toOut` and `toOutImage` are symbols that are originally defined within the loop that handles communication between the Kernel and Jupyter notebook. Kernel sends evaluated response but Jupyter does not understand MMA Box language so it needs to be something else. Currently it is implemented that it is either a plain **text**, an **image** or an [embedded **iFrame**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199737/5478) with contents deployed to cloud.

WLforJupyter loop makes a choice that it should be e.g. an image and does `toOut = toOutImage @ evaluationResults`

So the trick is to set `toOut` (1st line) and prevent it from being reset (2nd line). :)

Comment: Nice workaround, although it seems that the number of terms is limited. While this works `Sum[c[i],{i,1,7670}]`,  increasing the number to 7675 returns `$Failed`. Using `Shallow` helps, though, cf. `Shallow[Sum[c[i],{i,1,10000}]]`. At the moment I think that your idea is the best thing one can come up with, so I accept it as an answer.

Comment: @vsht does it return $Failed before applying the trick? If so that is probably something to report.

Comment: It seems to be related only to the output (also without your trick), the kernel evaluates the expression just fine. I created an issue on GitHub for that [here](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues/43). I also opened another [issue](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/issues/45) regarding `TraditionalForm` as the default cell output type, mentioning this question and your workaround.

Comment: It’s crazy that gifs don’t work in the cloud