# Interactive plots / output in Jupyter based interface

Tags: jupyter-notebook

#### Shortly

One can connect Wolfram Engine / Kernel to the Jupyter notebook thanks to [github / WRI / WLforJ](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter) and following manuals: [How to add a front-end to the free Wolfram Engine?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198839/5478)

Can I rotate `Graphics3D @ Sphere[]` generated in Jupyter notebook interface?

#### Background

The question was raised [**here**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-a-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine/199127#comment515121_198840). I assumed the answer is no. But while looking for an answer to [TraditionalForm-like typesetting in Jupyter notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199635/5478) I found a nice feature.

Comment: How do you do it without cloud I am using wolfram engine

Comment: One could try to use this project as well [WolframJSFrontend](https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend). It is still in alpha stage, but quite usable

Comment: @KirillVasin please add an answer with a short steps/description

Answer (score 21):

Wolfram Kernel <-> Jupyter loop related definitions can be read from files in

https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

One can learn that within a loop a special wrapper is defined: `Interact`.

When connected to the Wolfram Cloud, input that is wrapped with `Interact` will be deployed to the Cloud and embedded in the jupyter notebook:

[image]

Comment: Very cool! I only recently learned that this could be possible, but I didn't expect someone to implement it this quickly. Kudos!

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I didn't implement it :P I just found it :)

Comment: Kudos for finding it :P.

Comment: Strange, this didn't work for me. Do you have to enable something?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a Jupyter-based solution, but might be still useful.

[WolframJSFrontned](https://github.com/JerryI/wolfram-js-frontend)

[image]

[image]

[image]

The project is based purely on Wolfram Engine/ Kernel and minimal notebook interface written in JS. It brings similar experience with cells, interactive Graphics (recreated using Three.js and Ploty.js), editable output cells and the paradigm of Mathematica, where everything is a syntax sugar. Exporting to standalone .html file is also possible. Web server is written in Wolfram Language and connects via websockets to the very primitive Wolfram language JS interpreter. The architecture is flexible and easy to expand, adding a new functions (js representation s for the graphical functions) is not a big deal.

It is still is early alpha stage and actively developing. Manipulate and other dynamics are on the way.

Use git clone and run a single wolframscript file via CMD, after that - just open http://127.0.0.1:8090

Hope it can help you