# How does I install the Wolfram Engine on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: linux, free-wolfram-engine

I just downloaded wolframscript on Windows. I got WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh. I tried executing it but it showed me
[image].

I use 'ls‘ but it also showed me
[image]

I'm sure that the file is in the folder, but I can't find it. How can I do? Please help me.

I have read any web I can find, but none told me why there is not file.

Yeah, I don't explain it well. I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). As usual, I can download .sh files from windows and open it in linux subsystem. But now I can't find 'WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh'. So I ask this problem...
[image]
I can't install  WolframEngine, so I can't do anything as these webs...

Comment: I have seen it. But I can't install wolfram engine...you see?@user1066

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a front-end to the free Wolfram Engine?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-a-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine)

Comment: emm,it's Windows Subsystem for Linux(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). I download something in windows and open it in linux@user1066. Maybe I need to ask this question in microsoft bbs.

Comment: No, you don't understand my problem. It's my fault. Please look at my new revision.@AntonAntonov

Comment: I think this is a question for the Windows Stack Exchange, not the Mathematica one. I would consider simply moving the file and seeing if it works from a new location :)

Comment: In fact, I have try it. But it doesn't work. My linux subsystem only haves three folders...@CarlLange

Comment: If my memory is correct, you cannot drop files from Windows land directly into the WSL folders.  I would just download it into your user's download folder and then run it in WSL from `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Downloads`.

Comment: [Files created from Windows does not show up in bash](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/552) and [WSL file system support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/) of help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about Mathematica or Wolfram Language. The problem is related to OP's operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

**In Windows 10:**

> 1. Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from Microsoft Store (free app)
>
>    > ```
>    > a.  also known as Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows
>    > b.  installation required setting Developer Mode in Settings
>    > ```
> 2. Download Wolfram Engine from www.wolfram.com (free app)
>
>    > ```
>    > a.  wolfram ID & password required for download and for activation
>    > b.  download to Windows default folder, Downloads in my case
>    > ```
> 3. Launch the Ubuntu subsystem from the start menu

**In the Ubuntu subsystem**

> 4. Move the downloaded file to home directory.

```
cd $HOME 
mv /mnt/c/Users/louis/Downloads/WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh $HOME
```

> 5. Install Wolfram Engine.  It was already executable, so `chmod` was not necessary.  Without the "./" in front, I got the "command not found message".  I installed to the default directory.
>
> `sudo ./WolframEngine_12.0.0_LINUX.sh`
>
> 6. Test drive the executable `/usr/bin/wolframscript`
>      Entered my Wolfram ID & password and then got the "In[1]:= " prompt.