# How do you run Wolfram Language code in VSCode?

Tags: interoperability

I have recently gotten into learning the Wolfram Language with Mathematica, I honestly love Mathematica, but my trial has recently ended, and I do not want to go through the mess of installing Eclipse; does anybody know of any way to run Wolfram Language code on VSC?

I already have the Wolfram Kernel up and running.

Comment: Esp. if you are a new Wolfram Language user, I would recommend trying to find another way to get access to a proper Wolfram system, e.g., using a Raspberry Pi.

Running WL on VSC is most likely a very tiny use case, you probably won't get much help if you run into a problem.

Comment: Are you aware of [How to add a front-end to the free Wolfram Engine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198839/106)

Comment: Maybe helpful [VSCode extension with custom Wolfram Language Server](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1589399)

Answer (score 2):

First download and install Wolfram engine on your machine. Then [install a jupyter kernel](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter) for Wolfram Language.

In VSCode open a file using .ipynb extension and select the wolfram kernel.

Voila!

Comment: I do this as you suggested, but I can't find wolfram kernel.

Comment: https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommended the https://github.com/njpipeorgan/wolfram-language-notebook, I've been using it with free wolfram engine for several months.

Pros:

1. you have all the power from vscode. onhover, highlight, format  <s>(PR, waiting for merge)</s>  see https://github.com/asukaminato0721/mmafmt , dynamic powered by player https://github.com/asukaminato0721/mmaplayer
2. even the kernel crashes, your code is safe.

Cons:

1. you can only get the interactive animations from wolfram player.
2. FrontEnd relate operation is not available. For example, `CopyToClipboard`
3. Only 1 dimension input.