# Speak[] function using Wolfram Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, sound

I wrote a program for practicing note identification on a guitar:

```
note1 = {"A.", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
note2 = {" Sharp", " Natural", " Flat"};
string = {"first  ", "second  ", "third  ", "fourth ", "fifth ", 
   "sixth "};

list = StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{note1, note2}];
list2 = Flatten[
   Table[RandomSample[StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{string, list}]], {i, 
     1, 1}]];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[list2], i++,
 Speak[list2[[i]]];
 Pause[2.5];
 ]
```

I do not have a Mathematica license, so I want to use Wolfram Cloud. The problem is that the server times out before the for-loop gets through the entire list. Is there anyway to send the speak command to the server, then have it send back the entire list in audio format?

Comment: If you don't have a *Mathematica* license, and *Wolfram Cloud* is not a solution for you, you can still use [*Wolfram Engine*](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) and [*Jupyter Notebook* as a front-end](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198839/10397), both free to install and use (some restrictions apply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on Wolfram Cloud:

```
note1 = {"A.", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
note2 = {" Sharp", " Natural", " Flat"};
string = {"first  ", "second  ", "third  ", "fourth ", "fifth ", 
   "sixth "};

list = StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{note1, note2}];
list2 = Flatten[
   Table[RandomSample[StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{string, list}]], {i, 
     1, 1}]];
pauseTime = 2;(*in seconds*)
audio = AudioJoin[
   AudioPad[#, pauseTime] & /@ SpeechSynthesize /@ list2]
```

To speed the spoken part up, add `AudioTimeStretch` with an appropriate factor. I had to rewrite the code a bit, as Wolfram Cloud doesn't seem to like too many nested `Map`-functions. Adjust `audioSpeed` to taste:

```
Clear[note1,note2,string,list,list2,pauseTime,audio,audioSpeed];
note1 = {"A.", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
note2 = {" Sharp", " Natural", " Flat"};
string = {"first  ", "second  ", "third  ", "fourth ", "fifth ", 
   "sixth "};
   list = StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{note1, note2}];
list2 = Flatten[
   Table[RandomSample[StringJoin[#] & /@ Tuples[{string, list}]], {i, 
     1, 1}]];
pauseTime = 2;(*in seconds*)
audioSpeed=0.9;(*Values < 1 for speeding up*)
   speedaudio=AudioJoin[Riffle[AudioTimeStretch[SpeechSynthesize[#],audioSpeed,Method->"Speech"]&/@list2,AudioGenerator["Silence",pauseTime]]]
```

Comment: This is great thanks! The speaking seems a little slow though, is there any way to speed those parts up?

Comment: Do you mean the pause between each called note and string is too long or the spoken part itself is too sluggish?

Comment: The spoken part is a bit too sluggish

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.