# Computing expectation with some constants

Tags: probability-or-statistics, wolfram-alpha-queries

I would like to compute the following expression in Wolfram alpha:
$$\mathbb{E}[X-max(aX+b,0)] $$
where $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $a,b$ are some constants.

Without constants, I can get the result with

> expectation of (x-max(x,0)), x normal distributed

However, the following doesn't seem to work:

> expectation of (x-max(ax+b,0)), x normal distributed

Do you know how I can get the general result with some arbitrary constants ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on Wolfram Alpha is considered off-topic in this site: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is "aX". This is interpreted as one variable name. You need a space between names. Then the following works:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Expectation[x - Max[a x - b,0], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I am quite new and I tried this on Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Clear%5B%22Global%60*%22%5D+Expectation%5Bx+-+Max%5Ba+x+-+b%5D%2C+x+%5C%5BDistributed%5D+NormalDistribution%5Bmu%2C+sig%5D%5D but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to use the paid version ?

Comment: Thanks for your response ! To compute this expression, I need Mathematica ? The online free Wolfram Alpha is not enough ?

Comment: I tried it on WolframAlpha, but it seems that WolframAlpha does not know about "Expectation"

Comment: Thanks. I will install the trial version of Mathematica then...

Comment: I think you forgot the zero in the `Max` function:  `Expectation[x - Max[0, a x + b], 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]`.

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Comment: @Wiles01 You can install the full version for free and use Jupiter notebook interface https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-a-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine.

Comment: Thanks ! What does "True" mean in the last case of the output ?

Comment: True means: all other cases

Comment: You can get a simpler result if you simplify using the constraints on `mu` and `sig` required for the distribution to be valid, i.e., `mu \[Element] Reals && sig > 0`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that simplification.